# Getting/Indexing what Named-Entities have said/quoted

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, article

I am trying to semi-automatically identify what people/advisers/economists or the like say on the news:

## 1

But Barclays chief economist Kieran Davies said companies were simply opting against bank funding.
“I don’t think there’s actually a ­constraint on corporate credit from the banks. I think it’s more the case that ­corporates in recent years have either had sufficient cash or access to offshore funding to enable them to do their investment,” Mr Davies said.

## 2

The the amount of commercial lending for every dollar of residential property lending has plunged from $3.84 to $1.62 over the past 25 years, says ­analysis from Industry Super Australia.
“Consistent analysis demonstrates that we have a systematic issue ­transitioning national savings to real productive capital, such as nation-building infrastructure,” chief ­executive David Whiteley said.

## 3

Following the settlement, Macquarie’s then chief executive in Asia, Alex Harvey, said he was “quite ­encouraged about SATC, about the risk management framework we’ve now put in place over the last few years and the sort of opportunities that are in front of the trust.”

so with example #1, i would like to get what Mr Davies was saying,
and with example #2, what chief executive David Whiteley was saying,
and with example #3, what Alex Harvey was saying.

what is the best way of getting / indexing what those 3 people said in other 10000 or more articles ?
it feels like a mixed of Name-Entity-Tagging and Relationship-Extraction. Is there a more specific name to what I want to achieve ?

Comment: Try quotation detection or something. Here are two articles: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D/D13/D13-1101.pdf and http://langtech.jrc.it/Documents/0709_RANLP_Quotation-detection_BP-RS-CB_final.pdf

Comment: Thanks. THis is indeed what i want. now if only the software mentioned in the papers is open source...

Comment: If you find an open source tool, please post an answer here. I'll be happy to compare it with mine :)

Comment: Semantic Role Labeling might as well be useful...

Comment: i found stanford nlp parser might be giving me enough info, digging into that